# How to get child object name from child relationshipname using Apex?

Tags: apex, sobject, relationships

Example:

- Parent Object Name: Opportunity
- Child relationship Name: OpportunityLineItems
- Child object Name: OpportunityLineItem

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE. I am not sure what you're trying to ask. Can you elaborate? Also, I recommend you check out the [ask] article. It contains great tips to make your questions easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, I got my answer.

Comment: Hello @SebastianKessel I got my answer that I was looking, can I delete this question? Later I found the question is duplicate, some other places in the community, I also got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getRelationshipName to determine the name:

```
for(ChildRelationship rel: SobjectType.Opportunity.childRelationships) {
    System.debug(rel.getRelationshipName());
    System.debug(rel.getChildSObject());
    System.debug(rel.getField());
}
```

Please note that not all relationships have a name. Note also that you can't get the parent sObject, it's presumed you already know it, since you needed a describe to get there to begin with.

To find a specific relationship, you need to iterate through all the relationships:

```
ChildRelationship desiredRelation;
for(ChildRelationship rel: SobjectType.Opportunity.childRelationships) {
    if(rel.getRelationshipName() == 'OpportunityLineItems') {
        desiredRelation = rel;
        break;
    }
}
System.debug(desiredRelation.getChildSObject());
```